# How to avoid underflow trying to zero out elements

Tags: python, numpy, underflow

I have a big numpy 2d array `F` which has complex numbers (`np.complex64`). It has a lot of very small numbers. For the sake of my calculation, I only need precision of ~1e-6 - 1e-9. Since this matrix is very large, I am trying to use a sparse matrix representation. So I try to do this:

```py
np.seterr(all="raise")
...
F = getF()
F[np.abs(F) < EPSILON] = 0
# EPSILON = 1e-9. It is supposed to be in between 1e-6 and 1e-9
return csr_matrix(F)
```

But the computing the absolute value gives an underflow error (with numpy set to raise errors):

```
FloatingPointError: underflow encountered in absolute
```

Numpy doesn't raise an error if the `seterr` is not done, but just puts out NaNs which leads to problems as this matrix F is the starting point of a series of calculations.

From what I have read, the underflow is mainly handled by taking log and using the log values directly instead of the main ones, but in this case, I want to discard them all anyway. Is there a sane way of doing so? I thought of `np.clip` but I have complex number data so using it is not very straightforward.

So my question is whether there exists an elegant (and hopefully canonical) way of handling this?

Comment: What value is `EPSILON`?

Comment: @dawg, `EPSILON = 1e-9`, but its intended range is somewhere between 1e-6 and 1e-9. I have added it in the question as an edit.

Comment: If I do `a=np.array([np.float64(f"1e-{x}") for x in range(1,22)])` then do `a[np.abs(a)<1e-6]=0` I am unable to replicate this behavior...

Comment: Can you please post an MCVE?

Comment: I cannot reproduce with `a=np.array([np.csingle(1/10**x) for x in range(1,22)])` and `a[np.abs(a)<1e-6]=0` either.

Comment: What versions of Python and numpy do you have? There is some chatter about this with older versions...

Comment: @dawg can you reproduce the error with my example?

Comment: Yes, it does, but you can fix it with `F[np.abs(F.real) < eps ] = 0` in the `A:` block.

Comment: @dawg note that you have to apply this separately to the real and imaginary part (see block `B`), you would clip `1e-11 + 1j*17` to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, I can reproduce your error.
As dawg pointed our this doesn't happen if you take `float` instead of `complex`.
This is also the reason why option B works as the real and imag part are both arrays of floats.
Another option (C) would be to use more bits to represent your data, I guess complex128 is the default for numpy.

```py
import numpy as np
np.seterr(all="raise")
eps = 1e-9

def get_F(n=100):
    # generate some random data with some really small values
    r, i = np.random.random((2, n, n))**50
    F = r + 1j*i
    return F.astype('complex64')


# A: fails
F = get_F()
F[np.abs(F) < eps] = 0

# B: clip real and imag separatly
F = get_F()
F.real[np.abs(F.real) < eps] = 0
F.imag[np.abs(F.imag) < eps] = 0

# C: use more bits to represent your data
F = get_F()
F = F.astype('complex128')
F[np.abs(F) < eps] = 0

print('nonzeros in F:', np.count_nonzero(F))
```